# pdf is printing 10 pages off

Tags: 15.10, printing, hp, pdf, mate

I have a [data-sheet for a motherboard](http://nanocluster.umeche.maine.edu/bioTage/pcm9577.pdf) I am working with:
I tried to print page 136, but 126 came out of my printer.
I thought ok, sometimes the pages don't match up exactly between the document and the pdf. In this case they did. So I tried printing again, the same thing happed, and I got page 126. So then I tried printing page 146, which gave me page 136.  I did get what i want, but this shouldn't be happening. ..

whats wrong here?
I am using Ubuntu mate 15.10, with HPLIP, and the Atril Document Viewer 1.10.2

has anyone heard of something like this, and or know a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document you linked doesn't count the table of contents, the toc is numbered in roman numerals and then the pages start with number 1. If you use evince, it shows both real count as the "pdf count":

[image: PDF count on white background, real count on grey]